# JPA + Spring Boot: TransactionRequiredException on CRUD operations

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, entitymanager

I am likely missing something very fundamental to how JPA is used, but I am getting `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available` when I try to perform CRUD operations from a DAO, specifically operations that alter the database. I am using Spring Boot.

This is a toy example that gives the setup of my code, as you'll notice all the methods called from the EntityManager that just poll information work, but as soon as I try to alter the database somehow I have problems:

```
@Repository
public class PersonJpa{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void foo() {

        Long id = 500l;
        Person p = new Person(id, "lastName", "firstName");

        // all of these calls work:
        em.find(Person.class, id);
        em.contains(p);
        em.getReference(Person.class, id);

        // this call causes exception:
        em.remove(p);
    }
}
```

Here is my Spring Boot configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {Info.BASE_PACKAGE})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {Info.BASE_PACKAGE})
public class PersonServiceConfiguration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(PersonServiceConfiguration.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is my `application.yml` file:

```
spring:
    profiles.active: default

---

spring:
    profiles: default

spring.datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?autoReconnect=true
    username: user
    password: pwd

spring.jpa.show-sql: false
spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `@Transactional` to the class doing the CRUD, and also make sure the class invoking the CRUD class, has a transaction to join.